# Likert-scale data as DV... curious as to which regression model to use

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, categorical-data, likert, continuous-data

I have a 1-10 Likert scale as my DV and five variables as my IV. My IVs include both continuous and categorical variables.

I am wondering which independent variables have a major effect on my dependent variable, which a regression model would help with.

I was wondering if you had any suggestions as to which regression model I should use. What do you think of an ordinal logistic regression model? Thanks! :)

Comment: You can use structure equation modelling instead

Comment: By "scale", do you mean a Likert scale proper, which is composed of several individual items or questions, summed or averaged together?

Comment: By scale I mean 1-10 like, 1 = not at all likely and 10 = very likely. @mahimkhan thanks for the suggestion. What do you think of using an ordinal logistic regression model?